# Unable to pass 2 test cases out of 100

Tags: c++, string

The question states: Two strings **A** and **B** comprising of lower case English letters are compatible if they are equal or can be made equal by following this step any number of times:

Select a prefix from the string **A**(possibly empty), and increase the alphabetical value of all the characters in the prefix by the same valid amount. For example, if the string is **xyz** and we select the prefix **xy** then we can convert it to **yz** by increasing the alphabetical value by 1. But if we select the prefix **xyz** then we cannot increase the alphabetical value.
Your task is to determine if given strings **A** and **B** are compatible.

The logic here is that the difference of lower indices of the two string should never increase that of higher indices. That is what I did. And the two test cases are really long but not longer than what we can store in string type. That is why I have not provided it here.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(0);

string s1;
string s2;
cin>>s1>>s2;
long long int count=0,max=0;
if(s2.length()!=s1.length())
{
 cout<<"NO";
 return 0;
}
for(int i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
{
 if(s1[i]==s2[i])
     break;
 else
     count++;
}
for(int i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
{
   if(s2[i]-s1[i]>=max && s2[i]-s1[i]>0 && s2[i]-s1[i]<26)
     max= s2[i]-s1[i];

   else
   {
      cout<<"NO";
      return 0;
   }
 }
 cout<<"YES";

 return 0;
}
//The tester correct code is as follows:

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string a,b;
 assert(cin>>a>>b);
 assert(a.size()>=1 && a.size()<=1e6);
 assert(b.size()>=1 && b.size()<=1e6);
 bool f=1;
 if(a.size()!=b.size())f=0;
 else
 {
    int val=30;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        assert(a[i]>='a' && a[i]<='z');
        assert(b[i]>='a' && b[i]<='z');
        int temp=b[i]-a[i];
        if(temp>val || temp<0){f=0;break;}
        val=temp;
    }
 }
 if(f)cout<<"YES\n";
 else cout<<"NO\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problem, do you have access to the input data for the failing tests? Then you could just [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) with that data, to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Can you give the source of this question?

Comment: @GauravSingh [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/string-algorithm/basics-of-string-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/aliceandstrings-9da62aa7/)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The test files are really long. I'm unable to copy it at once in my compiler. You can check the question I Have provided a link in the previous comment.